# Why does the DOM have both window and self?

Tags: javascript, dom

Why does the DOM have an object called `self` and another called `window` when they are the same thing?  To add to the confusion `window` has a property called `self` so:

```
window === window.self === self
```

Why is it like this?  Which one should I use?

Comment: Why do you need to reference either?
`window` is part of the DOM, while `self` is relating to the global object in javascript, which happens to be equal to DOM's window in most implementation. In non-browser implementations like Rhino, `self`is present, but not `window` as there is no DOM.

Comment: @Sean: `self` does not appear in the Javascript (ECMAScript) standard. To reliably access the global object by name across implementations, you have to give it a name yourself, by executing something like this in the global context (outside of any functions): `var global = this;`  That works because when control enters the global context's code, `this` points to the global object. `self` doesn't make any sense as a name for the global object outside of the `window.self` context IMHO.

Comment: @T.J Was just about to add the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` is defined by the javascript environment and points to the [global] object (but is not part of the spec, so might not be there), while `window` is part of the DOM specification. 
In most browsers the `window` is used as the [global] object, but this is not always so.

That `self == window.self` is not strange as they are the same object - when `self` is being looked up, it is found as a property of the global object (`window`). So it is in fact the same as `window.self == window.self`.

As noted elsewhere, to reliable reference the `[global]` object, you should define it your sef by running `var global = this;` in the global execution context.

Comment: I understand that both are pointers to the same object.  It just caught me as weird that an object of the DOM has as a property itself because it is not evident why anyone would intentionally design something to be like that.

Comment: Its not weird at all if you know of the execution contexts are built up in ECMAScript. Afterall, the `self` property has to be defined somewhere accessible right? And that is as a property of the `[global]` object itself. That the property actually points to the `[global]` object is not really relevant here.

Comment: So are you saying that `self` is like `var global = this;` in the global execution context?  I guess my question is: why does `self` exist if the browser gives us `window`?

Comment: Wait is it because `self` used here is a global variable and all global variables are properties of the global JavaScript object which is also called `window` by browsers?

Comment: Because in the ECMA spec there is not direct reference to the `[global]` object, so some implementers extended the implementation with `self`. Now remember that DOM is not really bound to javascript (equally accessible with vbscript in IE) so `window` is not really part of the equation when defining the global object. BUT as stated the DOM's window object is normally used as the `[global]` object.

Comment: @hekevitran That is pretty much it, although the [global] object isn't 'called' window, its the DOMs window that is _used_ as the global object. Its not really easy to explain using comments only :)

Comment: @hekevintran: *"Wait is it because `self` used here is a global variable and all global variables are properties of the global JavaScript object which is also called `window` by browsers?"* Yes. In fact, the global varible `window` is, itself, a property of the global object, just like `self`, just like my `global` example. This is because the global object (`window`, on browsers) is the "binding object" of the global execution context. http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Comment: Right, I get it now.  That was a lot simpler than I thought it was :)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that in ECMAScript 5th's strict mode (`"use strict";`), `var global = this;` would fail, because trying to access the global object is a violation in strict mode.  Try it for yourself at JSLint.com.

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling `self` it **is** `window.self`, so same thing there like any other global property (e.g. `location` is really `window.location`).

The reason it's there?  Usually for checks like this:

```
if(window.top != window.self) {
  alert("We're in a frame");
}
```

Comment: @T.J. If `window.top` and `window.self` have changed types you have bigger issues in your JS :)  As for the first check, yes you could use `window`, but `window.self != window.top` is a lot *clearer* was my point :)

Comment: Gotcha. (And on type: Yeah, but hey, it could happen! `window.top = "frog";` ;-) )

Comment: @T.J. Oh it can definitely happen :) Older IE letting you redefine the `window` object itself, good times

Answer (score 0):

The global `self` is a shortcut to `window.self`. They are both the very same object.

As to why there are both `window` and `self`, in a web page context, `self` is always equal to `window` (as far as I know). But I guess this doesn't have to always be that way - Javascript/ECMAScript is not limited to use in a web page where there is a DOM.

As to what to use, both should be safe to use in a normal web page context AFAIK. See @Nick's comment for good arguments for using `window`, though.

Comment: I wouldn't use `self` personally...many frameworks/misc code use this as a local variable internally and possibly in the closure you're feeding it, so `self` may *not* be `window.self` in some cases.