# Why won't this jQuery work in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm working on a site someone else developed. They used the following jQuery code to produce the drop down in the menu:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var site_menu_categories_tID = null;
            $(document).ready(
                function(){
                    $("#site-menu-categories").click(
                        function(){
                            self = $(this);
                            $(".submenu-holder").show();
                        }
                    );
                    $("#site-menu-categories").mouseleave(
                        function(){
                            site_menu_categories_tID = setTimeout(function(){
                                $(".submenu-holder").trigger('mouseleave');
                                clearTimeout(site_menu_categories_tID);
                                site_menu_categories_tID=null;
                            },500);
                        }
                    );
                    $(".submenu-holder").mouseenter(
                        function(){
                            if(site_menu_categories_tID!=null){
                                clearTimeout(site_menu_categories_tID);
                                site_menu_categories_tID=null;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    $(".submenu-holder").mouseleave(
                        function(){
                            self = $(this);
                            self.hide();
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        </script>
```

It works fine in firefox but not in any of the IE's (8 and below haven't tested in 9). Are there any apparent errors that you can see?

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors when opening up IE8?

Comment: To avoid cluttering the global scope, get rid of the first `self = $(this);` and add `var` to the second one or simply replace those two lines with `$(this).hide();`

Comment: Is the site being displayed in standards mode or quirks mode?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: the site is in standards mode. I go get an error but it's not indicvative of anything, just says "o-recent not implemented".

Comment: @ThiefMaster ahh awesome, your tip did the trick. If you post it as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Heh, i'd have never expected IE to choke on a global var named `self`.. but well, it's IE. Answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid cluttering the global scope, get rid of the first `self = $(this);` and add `var` to the second one or simply replace those two lines with `$(this).hide();`

Apparently IE doesn't like you naming a global variable `self`.

Comment: this is the right course. self already exists at the global scope, so the code is overwriting it. IE8 is probably trying to call it somewhere and finding a jQuery object. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797531/why-does-the-dom-have-both-window-and-self